# When is a TextFile not a TextFile?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, web

I have 2 Text Files.  One I am serving as static content.  The other I am serving out of my Azure Storage.

1. https://municipalagenda.com/Content/files/sample-talk-clip.txt
2. https://municipalstorage.blob.core.windows.net/texttracks/3f782a63-3ecc-444c-aa9c-8e450218b16f.txt

The first one is behaving well.  I can set my Model attribute: `@Model.VideoTextTrackSrc` to it, and it will work.

The second one is not behaving.

```
<video loop controls>
    <source src="@Model.MeetingVideo" >
    <track label="Live Captioning Example Captions" kind="captions" srclang="en" src="@Model.VideoTextTrackSrc" id="caption-change-track" default>
</video>
```

I did notice that if I drop them both in Chrome, the 1st one loads inline, the 2nd one downloads.

I need to make the Azure Storage URLs behave like the static content.

**EDIT** I went into Azure and made it serve the file up as `text/vtt`.  It looks good when I click on it in Chrome, but it's still not behaving well in the src attribute of the `<track>` tag.

Here is the new Link:

https://municipalstorage.blob.core.windows.net/texttracks/73b28cac-8dac-4d97-94f9-2dfe977b01ca.vtt

I also tried text/plain and .txt to do apples-to-apples, no go there either:

https://municipalstorage.blob.core.windows.net/texttracks/13ffb0bd-7b07-4dda-9fc4-6448696d6292.txt

Comment: has to do with server side settings (headers) that are forcing download

Comment: First has Content-Type: text/plain, Second has Content-Type: application/octet-stream, so is treated as generic blob of data.

Comment: @Evk Thank you that makes perfect sense.  Any idea on how I can force the 2nd one Content-Type to text/plain?  Is that something I can put in the tag, or does that need to come from Azure Storage?

Comment: I cannot say for sure that track tag requires source to have valid content type (though it seems reasonable). If that is true - you need to adjust your server side to set correct Content-Type header. I have no experience with azure so cannot tell exact steps.

Comment: Also note that it's better to use .vtt extension and text/vtt mime type for such files.

Comment: @Evk, I updated Azure so it's serving it up as text/vtt and .vtt extension.  I can click on it in Chrome but it's still not working in my tag.  Was wondering if you could take a look or let me know how you figured out the Content-Type of the original 2 links.

Comment: @Evk PS I did also try text/plain, no go there either.

Comment: @Evk Please upgrade your post to an answer and I will accept it.  By the way, I got my final issue resolved, it turned out to be CORS-based issues.

Comment: But aftet all, content type had any effect or it was CORS all the way?